# Xbox One S Bluetooth controller causing weird frame drops

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, windows-10

Whenever I use my xbox one s controller, connected via bluetooth and I play a game with rumble/vibration the frames will drop to half, sometimes more than half while it's rumbling and return to normal afterwards. For example, in one game I get ~400 FPS but as soon as the rumble starts it sharply drops to ~115. 115 is still great for this game and it would be very smooth at that FPS as well, but when this happens it gets very choppy (the choppiness doesn't happen anymore after I updated the controller firmware but the frame drops do).

I'm not sure what's going on here but I'm now very curious for an answer. This isn't so much asking how to fix something (although if someone knows how, please answer) than it is wanting to understand why it's happening. I've tried to google a reason this would be happening but all I can find are a lot of other people having the same problem, for years.

This is on a brand new system, i9-9900K, intel wireless/bluetooth, EVGA 2080 ti kingpin, all m.2 ssd drives, latest Windows 10 update. My xbox controller is admittedly a bit old but I have updated the firmware as of today. I also have nothing else connect via bluetooth. Any insight into why this is happening would be fantastic, as I lack the low level hardware debugging skills and tools to figure it out on my own.

Fresh batteries are in the controller and my bluetooth antenna is about 2 feet away from the controller.

EDIT: The frame drops don't happen when the controller is connected via USB

Comment: Is it any game? Or just a specific game?

Comment: What game is it? It may be a game specific problem. Does it happen with other games as well? Are you playing through another platform (eg Steam big picture) or just running the game via an .exe file?

Comment: It happens on more than 1 game. I notice it in any game that has controller support and uses rumble. Most recently it's been battle chasers and some platformer that I don't recall the name of off the top of my head